# how to show selected item in dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I have the code shown below [I am using JQuery and Bootstrap 4]:

```js
$('.dropdown-menu li').on('click', function() {
  var getValue = $(this).text();
  $('.dropdown-select').text(getValue);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.7.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-auto p-2 col-5">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button id="dLabel" class="dropdown-select" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
         Select
        <span class="caret"></span>
     </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
      <li>Option 1</li>
      <li>Option 2</li>
      <li>Option 3</li>
      <li>Option 4</li>
      <li>Option 5</li>
      <li>Option 6</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

by clicking any dropdown option, not selected and don't show on it.

Comment: please clarify what the problem is...

Comment: is there a reason why you aren't using the default html component for drop down lists "select" ? Maybe using this will make things easier for you

Answer (score 0):

Push away from the `<li>` you choose, because there can be more than one `.dropdown` on the page.
And just add the `active` class to `<li>` in this list.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu li', function() {
  const li = $(this);
  li.closest('.dropdown-menu').find('li').removeClass('active');
  li.addClass('active');
  li.closest('.dropdown').find('.dropdown-select').text( li.text() );
});
```

```css
.dropdown-menu .active {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.7.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-auto p-2 col-5">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button id="dLabel" class="dropdown-select" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
         Select
        <span class="caret"></span>
     </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
      <li>Option 1</li>
      <li>Option 2</li>
      <li>Option 3</li>
      <li>Option 4</li>
      <li>Option 5</li>
      <li>Option 6</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understood correctly. You need something like this:

1. Create index.html
2. create styles.css
3. create dropdown.js

```js
function myFunction() {
  var dropdownMenu = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  if (dropdownMenu.style.display === "block") {
    dropdownMenu.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dropdownMenu.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #000fb7;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#yourlink1">Option 1</a>
  <a href="#yourlink2">Option 2</a>
  <a href="#yourlink3">Option 3</a>
</div>
```

Defer means --- a script executed after the page has finished parsing

Comment: 1. I don't think this would be the answer and also his question is not clear
2. This does not solve any problem, you just added your custom CSS and js instead of bootstrap. You also removed the original functionality which is to show the selected value on label